# How can I restart my autoincrement in phpmyadmin?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have some tables in my phpmyadmin with one column that is auto incremented.

The problem is that when I delete some rows from the table (For example the element Car, with index auto incremented 1) and I create another row into the table, the new row have the index 2, but in the table there is only one row.

I want that this second element created to have the index equal to the position of the row, for example, if I have 3 rows that the third element will have the index equals to 3.

I was looking for a method that let me to use my phpMyAdmin like this but I couldn't find anything.

Is it possible? If it is true, what should I have to do? Do I have to create the table again?

Comment: This should not be an issue..... autoincrement is __not__ about creating consecutive id values, but about creating unique id values; you should never write code that is dependent on consecutive values

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7057272/560648 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, but you shouldn't do that on production.

The SQL query is:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```

The most important part of this is to prevent overriding. For example you have an user and this user has `id` of 81 and if you delete this user and the database doesn't remember that this `id` 81 has ever been taken by an user (and for example, you have some relations - like friend lists) the user that is going to have the same ID will probably have the same data.

So basically, you don't want to reset auto increment values.

Comment: _"the user that is going to have the same ID will probably have the same data"_ No, not if your foreign key constraints cascade properly.

Comment: Yep, that's right. I hadn't made it clear enough. Basically, the uniqueness of the column is lost. *imo*

Comment: @IvankaTodorova Thank you man! And where I have to execute this line?

Comment: @Error404, you said that you're using phpmyadmin. Just paste it in the SQL  tab and hit execute.

Comment: If you're assuming that an auto-incremented ID is always going to be a unique value, you've _already_ lost. IMO.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I'm sorry, can you elaborate? I read somewhere that by using an Identity Column, which MySQL's AI column is equivalent , uniqueness is guaranteed.

Comment: @IvankaTodorova: Well, wherever you read it, it was wrong. `AUTO_INCREMENT` columns auto-generate values. That's it. A `UNIQUE` key on that column isn't going to make such columns unique _for all time_ in the face of row deletions and the like, and you can modify the auto-generated value to your heart's content.

Answer (score 2):

This is generally a bad idea. Auto increment is used for creating unique ID of the row. Imagine you have a record "1 - John". Then you delete it and add another "1 - Jack". From the point of common database logic, it will seem that John was renamed to Jack (it has the same ID = it is the same entity) rather than it is another record. You should let DB assign new ID to each new record, even with leaving gaps after deleted records.

If you really want to do so, you can modify auto increment value using this query:

```
ALTER TABLE users AUTO_INCREMENT=123
```

but it is still not the way auto increment is designed for.

Comment: _"When you delete it and add another "1 - Jack". From the point of common database logic, it will seem that John was renamed to Jack (it has the same ID = it is the same entity) "_ Not really, not if your foreign key constraints cascade properly.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit All my tables contains cascade property. If I change my index column. It will be changed in all the tables, it's correct?

Comment: @Error404: Yes, it should be. Test to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

Execute this SQL sentence:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this a bit too, then found in the "Operations" tab, there is a setting under "Auto Increment" where you can set the number it will start from, so you can roll it back if you want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. It is not a feature of phpmyadmin, but of mysql. Execute this

```
ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```

More info on this on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923114/how-to-reset-auto-increment-in-mysql)

And in the [mysql reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html)